# How to append unique ID to a json array - OctoberCMS / Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel, octobercms

OctoberCMS BackendForm-Widget "Repeater" stores my data as an array in the database which looks like so:

```
    {
    "topic":"title",
    "topic_description":"description",
    }
    {
    "topic":"title",
    "topic_description":"description",
    }
```

I need to add a unique ID to each array so the json looks like this:

```
    {   
    "topic_id":"1",
    "topic":"title",
    "topic_description":"description",
    }  
    {   
    "topic_id":"2",
    "topic":"title",
    "topic_description":"description",
    }
```

I have added this formBeforeSave function to my controller:

```
public function formBeforeSave($model)
    {

        $model->topics = array_map(array($model, 'topics'), function ($topic) {
         $topic['id'] = uniqid();
        });
    }
```

But when trying to save the form OctoberCMS throws this error:

`“array_map(): Argument #2 should be an array”`

Adding this to the controller instead:

```
public function formBeforeSave($model)
{
    $model->topics = array_map($model->topics, function ($topic) {
         $topic['id'] = uniqid();
    });
}
```

Throws the error:

`array_map() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, array must have exactly two members`

Has anyone experienced this and found a solution he/she could share please?

Comment: each topic has a (unique) key. So you could just copy this key as additional value

Comment: Argument 1 should be the callback which you have provided as second argument.

Answer (score 0):

Each topic has a (unique) key already. So you could just copy this key as additional value while walking through the array:

```
// mocking test-data:
// $model->topics = [["topic"=>"title"], ["bar"=>"foo"]];

array_walk($model->topics, function(&$topic, $key) {
    $topic['topic_id'] = $key;
});
```

Comment: Thank you Jeff! Unfortunately that didn't work. I get the error:

`"Indirect modification of overloaded property Class::$topics has no effect"`

Answer (score 0):

As per the docs first argument should be callback, replace your code with following and try if it works.

```
public function formBeforeSave($model)
{
    $model->topics = array_map(function ($topic) {
         $topic['id'] = uniqid();
         return $topic;
    }, $model->topics);
}
```

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php

Comment: Hmm...it looks good but unfortunately doesn't have any effect. But at least there isn't any error. ;-)

Comment: For me it's working fine. Can you show what you have tried?

Comment: Didn't change anything from initial stated code above besides adding your snippet into my controller:

```
    public function formBeforeSave($model)
    {


        $model->topics = array_map(function ($topic) {
             $topic['id'] = uniqid();
             return $topic;
        }, $model->topics);
    }
```

But the json array looks the same and didn't change.
After that and for testing purpose i have deleted the column in the database. I recognized that when trying to save the first time, it throws an error:

Comment: `array_map(): Argument #2 should be an array`

I guess it does that because it can't find an array.
Then i commented out your snippet, stored an array by saving OctoberCMS BackendForm. Once i had a fresh array in the column i reactivated your snippet...but ... :-(  ...no good news. No id is being appended.
I changed the column to be a json and back to Text. Neither or helped.

Comment: Can you show the output of `var_dump($model->topics);`?

Comment: Well that is very strange now...  `var_dump($model->topics);` clearly shows that the ID has been added. But looking into the mysql db column i can't see that id.

Comment: Because you are trying to apply `array_map` to `$model->topics` therefore php expects `$model->topics` to be an array.

Comment: The purpose of all this is an API which gets generated based on all available data.
I just checked the API and unfortunately the ID is not been provided.
So seems like the id is being generated but not getting stored.

Comment: Update:
array gets updated BUT only in another column than it is supposed.
I have opened a request at OctoberCMS [Github] (https://github.com/octobercms/october/issues/4056#issuecomment-453923147)

Answer (score 0):

Applaus goes to [LukeTower](https://github.com/LukeTowers) who pointed me to the right direction on [Github](https://github.com/octobercms/october/issues/4056#issuecomment-454267240).

The solution is putting the logic in the beforeSave() method on the model:

```
    public function beforeSave()
{
    $this->_FieldName_ = array_map(function ($miau) {

        $miau['id'] = uniqid();
        return $miau;

    }, $this->_FieldName_);
}
```